# Regular Expression for each line starting with double hyphens

Tags: php, regex

I have a string from which I want to match and separate each lines starting with the double hyphens and replace those strings with h4 elements without the characters matching the double hyphens.

Here is the code I have.

```
$rcp_ingredients = '--For Salad 
    1 1/2 Cup warm water (105°F-115°F)
    2 1/4 Teaspoon active dry yeast
    --For glaze 
    1 cup packed dark brown sugar
    2 tablespoons finely chopped garlic
    1 tablespoon Tabasco
    --For Marination
    3 tablespoons fresh lime juice
    1 tablespoon fresh orange juice
    1 tablespoon Dijon mustard
    1 teaspoon curry powder, toasted
    1/2 teaspoon salt
    1/4 teaspoon black pepper
    1/2 cup olive oil ';

$list = explode("\n", $rcp_ingredients);

foreach ( $list as $key => $data ) {
    $data = preg_replace( '/\-{2}(\w+)/' , '<h4>$1</h4>', $data );
    $pos = strpos( $data, '<h4>' );
    if ( $pos === false ) {
        echo '<span class="name">' . $data . '</span>';
    } else {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
<h4>For</h4> Salad 
<span class="name">1 1/2 Cup warm water (105°F-115°F)
</span><span class="name">2 1/4 Teaspoon active dry yeast
</span><h4>For</h4> glaze 
<span class="name">1 cup packed dark brown sugar
</span><span class="name">2 tablespoons finely chopped garlic
</span><span class="name">1 tablespoon Tabasco
</span><h4>For</h4> Marination
<span class="name">3 tablespoons fresh lime juice
</span><span class="name">1 tablespoon fresh orange juice
</span><span class="name">1 tablespoon Dijon mustard
</span><span class="name">1 teaspoon curry powder, toasted
</span><span class="name">1/2 teaspoon salt
</span><span class="name">1/4 teaspoon black pepper
</span><span class="name">1/2 cup olive oil </span>
```

**What I want to get an output is.**

```
<h4>For Salad</h4>
<span class="name">1 1/2 Cup warm water (105°F-115°F)</span>
<span class="name">2 1/4 Teaspoon active dry yeast</span>
<h4>For Glaze </h4>
<span class="name">1 cup packed dark brown sugar</span>
<span class="name">2 tablespoons finely chopped garlic</span>
<span class="name">1 tablespoon Tabasco</span>
<h4>For Marination</h4>
<span class="name">3 tablespoons fresh lime juice</span>
<span class="name">1 tablespoon fresh orange juice</span>
<span class="name">1 tablespoon Dijon mustard</span>
<span class="name">1 teaspoon curry powder, toasted</span>
<span class="name">1/2 teaspoon salt</span>
<span class="name">1/4 teaspoon black pepper</span>
<span class="name">1/2 cup olive oil </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out.. The problem was

> **1.** `(\w+)` for a word like `For Salad` it contains words as well as spaces, if you want to grab everything starts with `--` you can use `^\s*\-{2}(.*)`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785413)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$rcp_ingredients = '--For Salad 
    1 1/2 Cup warm water (105°F-115°F)
    2 1/4 Teaspoon active dry yeast
    --For glaze 
    1 cup packed dark brown sugar
    2 tablespoons finely chopped garlic
    1 tablespoon Tabasco
    --For Marination
    3 tablespoons fresh lime juice
    1 tablespoon fresh orange juice
    1 tablespoon Dijon mustard
    1 teaspoon curry powder, toasted
    1/2 teaspoon salt
    1/4 teaspoon black pepper
    1/2 cup olive oil ';

$list = explode("\n", $rcp_ingredients);

foreach ($list as $key => $data)
{
    $data = preg_replace('/^\s*\-{2}(.*)/', '<h4>$1</h4>', $data);
    $pos = strpos($data, '<h4>');
    if ($pos === false)
    {
        echo '<span class="name">' . $data . '</span>';
    } else
    {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sahil. I was thinking to use .* which matches all but still had a confusion in regex101.com website

Comment: @Maqk Welcome... :) `.*` is for `match all`.

Answer (score 1):

With `(\w+)` you only match the first word (following `--`). Change it to "anything" to capture the entire string following the dashes:

```
$data = preg_replace( '/\-{2}(.*)/' , '<h4>$1</h4>', $data );
```